# How to make Telegram deep-linking work for messages?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I'm developing a bot, which creates games in Telegram.

When a user issues a `/start_game` command, the bot replies to user's command with a message, which includes a link to the created game.

Now when the same user issues the `/start_game` command again, the bot responds with something along the lines:

> Would you like to delete your **currently active game** and replace it with a new one?

The `currently active game` text should link to previously created game's message via Telegram Deep Linking.

The way I do this currently is by using this [deep link template from the docs](https://core.telegram.org/api/links#message-links):

```
f'<a href="tg://privatepost?channel={chat_id}&post={message_id}&single">{text}</a>'
```

Which worked fine under `Telethon`, but now that I switched over to `Python-Telegram-Bot`, it does not.

When clicked, such link says "Unfortunately you can't access this message. You aren't a member of the chat where it was posted.".

Well, I thought that the problem was because Telegram Bot API prefixes groups' ids with `-` and channels' ids with `-100`, so I got rid of those.

And now it says: "Message doesn't exist".

Actual code:

```
def message_mention(text: str, chat_id: int, message_id: int, escape: EscapeType | None = 'html'):
    text = escape_string(text, escape)
    if chat_id is None or message_id is None:
        return text

    chat_id_string = str(chat_id)
    if chat_id_string.startswith('-100'):
        chat_id_string = chat_id_string[4:]
    elif chat_id_string.startswith('-'):
        chat_id_string = chat_id_string[1:]

    return f'<a href="tg://privatepost?channel={chat_id_string}&post={message_id}&single">{text}</a>'
```

What am I missing here?

The `message_id` **must be** correct, because later in the same function if the user clicked "*Yes, delete the old game*", it deletes the mentioned message fine and dandy.

**UPD:**

Minimal reproducible example, which attempts to link to a command just issued by the user.

```
async def main():
    from telegram import Update
    from telegram.ext import ContextTypes
    from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
    from telegram.ext import Application, Defaults


    app = (
        Application
        .builder()
        .defaults(
            Defaults(
                parse_mode="html"
            )
        )
        .token(BOT_TOKEN)
        .build()
    )

    def message_mention_lonami(text: str, chat_id: int, message_id: int):
        chat_id_string = str(chat_id)
        if chat_id_string.startswith('-100'):
            chat_id_string = chat_id_string[4:]
        elif chat_id_string.startswith('-'):
            chat_id_string = chat_id_string[1:]

        return f'<a href="https://t.me/c/{chat_id_string}/{message_id}">{text}</a>'

    def message_mention(text: str, chat_id: int, message_id: int):
        chat_id_string = str(chat_id)
        if chat_id_string.startswith('-100'):
            chat_id_string = chat_id_string[4:]
        elif chat_id_string.startswith('-'):
            chat_id_string = chat_id_string[1:]

        return f'<a href="tg://privatepost?channel={chat_id_string}&post={message_id}&single">{text}</a>'


    async def handler(update: Update, ctx: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
        chat_id = update.effective_chat.id
        message_id = update.effective_message.id

        mention1 = message_mention_lonami("Solution by lonami", chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message_id)
        mention2 = message_mention("Default solution", chat_id=chat_id, message_id=message_id)

        await ctx.bot.send_message(
            chat_id,
            "\n".join([
                "is this your message?",
                mention1,
                mention2,
            ]),
        )

    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("test_mention", handler))

    async with app:
        try:
            await app.start()
            await app.updater.start_polling()
            await asyncio.Future()
        finally:
            await app.updater.stop()
            await app.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio
    asyncio.new_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Results in the client app:

[image: Message does not exist alert]
[image: Actual link of the both solutions]

Comment: If it's a private channel (megagroup or not), it might work with `t.me/c/channelid/msgid`, where `channelid` is the positive ID.

Comment: Please provide enough code so that we can reproduce the issue. In particular, your snippet does not show how you obtain the values that you pass to `chat_id` and `message_id`.

Comment: @CallMeStag thank you, I updated the question with a minimal reproducible example and the results of it inside telegram.

Comment: @Lonami thank you, I tested your link template, but to no avail, unfortunately. I updated the question with the example.

Comment: @CallMeStag is there something wrong with how I get the ids in the example? Because it seems to me there is no other way...

Comment: I'm not that familiar with deeplinking, so I can't really give more advice. However, it is very, very strange that the HTTP Bot API and Telethon, which talks directly with Telegram, behave differently for the same link - unless the HTTP Bot API or other libraries do something extra behind the scenes.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you try to link to a message in a private chat with the bot or a non-super group. The message links documented [here](https://core.telegram.org/api/links#message-links) are only available for supergroups and channels as can be infered from the description and the description of the `channel` parameter.
In fact, if run the example in a group or if I replace your `CommandHandler` with a `MessageHandler` and run the example in a channel, it works perfectly fine.

---

Disclaimer: I'm cururently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: I'm not linking a message in a private chat with the bot, why would you assume that?

Comment: It's a group, not a channel, in my case. So you're saying, I cannot link messages in a group? It may be the case. I'm gonna check that and if you're correct, I'm gonna accept the answer.
But still, there was nothing suggesting even remotely that I used that in a private chat.

Comment: Fair point. I made false assumptions based on the screenshot that looks like a private chat with the bot. I double checked with non-supergroups and updated my answer.